# passing url parameter array string to action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want call action method with something like this

```
http://server/controller/action/?idsTypes=[1, type1]&idsTypes=[2, type2]
```

Action method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult myMethod(string[][] idsTypes)
{
    ........
}
```

How change the url to pass the idsTypes parameter to method?

Thanks